# Keras Preprocessing Layer for Labels (Y)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, linear-regression, normalization, data-preprocessing

I have looked everywhere and cannot find answers to this. Basically, I am using pre-processing layers in Keras to normalize feature values for my model. My data is numeric, so I am using the below function to build the normalization layers:

```
# Used to normalize input features which are numeric - uses std deviation and mean
def get_normalization_layer(name, dataset):
    feature_ds = None
    dataset.map(lambda x, y: x[name])
    normalizer = layers.Normalization(axis=None)
    normalizer.adapt(feature_ds)
    return normalizer

...

numeric_col = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name=feature)
normalization_layer = get_normalization_layer(feature, train_ds)
encoded_numeric_col = normalization_layer(numeric_col)
```

This works great. Now I need to normalize the Y axis, and want to use preprocessing layers for this as well... how do I preprocess the labels **as part of the model**? Every single example I've found is for X axis, and for Y they use dataset.map() before compiling and running the model. I would like the entire pipeline self-contained as part of the model.

Thanks!

Comment: What do u mean by X/Y axis? Is the Y target vector?

Comment: Accessing the target vector (Y), it can be done by using subclass API (overriding the step function).

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the target - my mistake. With the features, you can feed them through processing layers into the model, and handle all the normalization in the model and on the GPU. Can you not do the same with target?

Comment: We can preprocess x and y from the data loader before passing them to model. But as mentioned you want to include the preprocessing function inside the model, it can also be done. But not in typical way as it's not usual to update y from model's high level API. You may need to override the step function. Check this doc, https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/

Answer (score 1):

Labels are never passed through the network: forward pass works only for the input data. You can normalize the outputs (predictions) using corresponding layers, but not the actual labels.

Targets are used when calculating the loss to optimize the weights of the network. **My first choice would be preprocessing the labels** beforehand before even starting the training. You seem to not like this solution, so my **second suggestion is: Integrate the preprocessing into loss function**

If you use a custom one, normalize the labels before the computation. If you use standard losses, you can override their call function with something like this:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.losses import Loss #the loss you use

class LossWithPreprocessing(Loss):
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred, *args, **kwargs):
        norm_y_true, norm_y_pred = some_preprocessing_func()
        return super().call(norm_y_true, norm_y_pred, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to avoid overriding loss functions, you can **subclass the [Model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) instead and implement label preprocessing** as part of `train_step` instead:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import Model

class ModelWithPreprocessing(Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = data
        y_normalized = some_normalization_func(y)
        return super().train_step((x,y))
```

as @Innat pointed in their comment, you can find more info about customizing fit [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit). Note that you must override the `test_step` method too to have a proper evaluation (model.eval()).

I personally don't like this solution. It feels a bit artificial to me - you do a work inside the network definition that isn't really a model's job.

Hope this helps!